# PHP How to divide weeks into days

Tags: php

How to enlist all the days between for instance 2018-06-04 and 2018-06-10 that between 2018-06-04 - 2018-06-10 those days will be 2018-06-05, 2018-06-06, 2018-06-07, 2018-06-08, 2018-06-09, the same goes for 2018-06-11 - 2018-06-17 and so on...

So far I'ive managed to divide month into week chunks (below), I want to further divide weeks into days...

```
2018-06-04 - 2018-06-10 
2018-06-11 - 2018-06-17 
2018-06-18 - 2018-06-24 
2018-06-25 - 2018-07-01
```

http://zakodowac.pl/

This is my PHP code which produces week chunks above 2018-06-04 - 2018-06-10 and so on...:

```
function getMondays($y, $m) {
    return new DatePeriod(
        new DateTime("first monday of $y-$m"),
        DateInterval::createFromDateString('next monday'),
        new DateTime("last day of $y-$m")
    );
}




function list_week_days($year, $month) {

    foreach (getMondays($year, $month) as $monday) {       

            echo  $monday->format(" Y-m-d\n");
        echo '-';
            $sunday  = $monday->modify('next Sunday');
            echo $sunday->format(" Y-m-d\n");
                        echo '<br>';

}

}


list_week_days(2018, 06);
```

Comment: Sorry if I get you correctly you are trying to get the number of days within the given dates?

Comment: no I want to enlist all the days between 2018-06-04 - 2018-06-10 , those days will be  2018-06-05, 2018-06-06, 2018-06-07, 2018-06-08, 2018-06-09

Comment: Can't you just do a `for ($i=1; $i<7; $i++)` loop adding $i days to Monday in each iteration?

Comment: for loop does not work. Try DateTime::add(new DateInterval('P1D')): http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php

Answer (score 0):

could you try this:

```
$begin = strtotime('2018-06-04');
$end = strtotime('2018-06-10');
while($begin < $end){
   $begin = $begin +84600;
   echo date('Y-m-d', $begin) . ' ';
}
```

Comment: Almost what I was going to suggest - but in a TZ with DST, this is going to return the same date twice in autumn (fall). If you explicitly set the timezone to UTC ("ETC/UTC") this will work. Alternatively start the clock at noon (12:00) instead of midnight (00:00) and `while(date('Ymd',$begin)<=date('Ymd',$end)){`

Comment: yeah thats a great idea

Answer (score 0):

if correctly understood, then the following should yield the results you expect:

```
// set current date
$date = '04/30/2009';
// parse about any English textual datetime description into a Unix timestamp 
$ts = strtotime($date);
// calculate the number of days since Monday
$dow = date('w', $ts);
$offset = $dow - 1;
if ($offset < 0) {
    $offset = 6;
}
// calculate timestamp for the Monday
$ts = $ts - $offset*86400;
// loop from Monday till Sunday 
for ($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++, $ts += 86400){
    print date("m/d/Y l", $ts) . "\n";
}
```

if you want to be even more clever, you can use:

```
// set current date
$date = '04/30/2009';
// parse about any English textual datetime description into a Unix timestamp 
$ts = strtotime($date);
// find the year (ISO-8601 year number) and the current week
$year = date('o', $ts);
$week = date('W', $ts);
// print week for the current date
for($i = 1; $i <= 7; $i++) {
    // timestamp from ISO week date format
    $ts = strtotime($year.'W'.$week.$i);
    print date("m/d/Y l", $ts) . "\n";
}
```

All of which, alongside more information, can be found on [this](https://www.redips.net/php/week-list-current-date/) website and credit goes to the author of that post.